# Installing GXT plugin in Eclipse

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm new to Java Enterprise.. I have search the web for the most efficient way to install GXT in my Eclipse 'JUNO' and i'm not getting the right steps to follow. Any one who can help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to do anything special. Just add the gxt.jar library in the build path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to get GWT up and running. You'll find a guide here: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/gettingstarted. Then to get GXT into the picture, create a new Web Application Project, add the gxt.jar to the classpath and add the following line to your project.gxt.xml file:

```
<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'/>
```

Sencha has a couple of tutorials on GXT at http://www.sencha.com/learn/gxt

Comment: Thanks Boss! i have actually figured it out in my Juno eclipse.